# Prevent deep link after reopening the backgrounded application

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, deeplink

I have an app Android with deep link via Browser.
I use the code below inside onCreate()

```
Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        if (appLinkIntent != null && appLinkIntent.getData() != null) {
            Uri data = getIntent().getData();
            List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
            id = params.get(1); // "id"
```

when finish the app return in browser page for next deep link.
If i reopen the app from "recent app" the deep link start with the previous data causing a duplicate.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode== RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //if (requestCode == 123 && data != null) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                //signature_signed_field_count = extras.getInt("signature_signed_field_count");
                ArrayList<String> firme = extras.getStringArrayList("signedSignatureFields");
                if (firme != null && !firme.isEmpty()) {
                   sendmail();
                } else {
                    pdf.delete();
                }
            }
            //other extras
            //data=null;
            setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
            //finishAffinity();
            super.finish();
        }
    }
```

Can i prevent this?